# Iptables drop all connection except my domain(s)

Tags: iptables, domain

I tried use this command to block a domain
`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j  REJECT`
and it worked but, i want to Reject all but accept from specified domains 
is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Before allowing a certain domain, block all other traffic:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

(this will drop all connections, even the ssh you might be using, so watch out)

Then, allow the domains you want:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j  ACCEPT
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but it didn't work, it dropped all connection and didn't allow the domain ...

Comment: Note the host lookup will fail if DNS traffic is blocked. Also keep in mind the host lookup is done once when the rule is loaded. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/218707/iptables-rules-to-allow-http-traffic-to-one-domain-only

Comment: but this command
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j  REJECT
is working ?

Comment: That's obviously not going to work, because the string you look for isn't present in every packet throughout the connection. In particular you are going to drop the SYN packets. Moreover, DROP is not the right target. You should be using `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`.